# Why does JavaScript object constructer prints only the first parameter value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

```js
var employee = ["Sam", "John", "Mark", "Peter", "Simon"]

var department = ["Sales", "Marketting", "Operation", "Finance", "Tech"]

var salary  = [40000, 60000, 50000, 60000, 70000]
const data=new Object(department,employee,salary);

console.log(data);
```

Why only print departments value?

Comment: Why are you using [`new Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object) in the first place? What do you expect `new Object(a, b, c)` to do and why?

Comment: how to store three array in single object @SebastianSimon

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). This is explained in every [JS tutorial about objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var employee = ["Sam", "John", "Mark", "Peter", "Simon"]

var department = ["Sales", "Marketting", "Operation", "Finance", "Tech"]

var salary = [40000, 60000, 50000, 60000, 70000] 

const data={department,employee,salary};
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Enclose the values by curly braces

```
const data = {department, employee, salary};
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: Please just [edit] in the future to make corrections. Do have extended discussions in the comments.